# php mongodb array_unique not working in cursor

Tags: php, mongodb, foreach

I have the following code that produces a list of roles:

```
// My original code (using find)
$cursor = $collection->find(array("organization" => $curr_org['organization'], "role" => array('$exists' => true)));

// The new code (using distinct)
$cursor = $collection->distinct('role', array("organization" => $curr_org['organization'], "role" => array('$exists' => true)));
foreach($cursor as $curr_org){
    echo '<ul>';
         echo '<li>';
              echo $curr_org['role'];
         echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

The Data contained in $curr_org['role'] has duplicates in it.

I've been messing around with `array_unique` and am unable to find the values of 'role'(getting array or NULL), or I'm getting the first and last values (id and organization).

My example document is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571626ac768d884c268b456b"),
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "email" : "jack@daniels.com",
    "manager" : "Jack Daniels",
    "role" : "Boss Man",
    "password" : "$2y$10$Bk8kVZaa0K.AJ7GqWT65LuTkWYVtNw8jK6Am5izcnvHAVBIxj5VHC",
    "organization" : "MyOrg"
}
```

Can anyone let me know where I should add the `array_unique` in my loop so I only product a list of unique roles?

Best Regards,
Dennis Hall

UPDATE:
Using distinct seems to work, however, it only echo's the first character of each role as follows:

Using Find:

```
Boss Man
Boss
Expeditor
Shift Manager
Ditch Digger
Boss
CEO
CEO
Expeditor
```

Using Distinct:

```
B
B
E
S
D
C
```

SOLVED:
The resolution was to use "distinct" in the cursor command. Also defining the key in the cursor command as well as in the loop caused the truncation of the results to a single letter. In the loop, the resolution was to remove the ['role'] from the echo $curr_org['role']; line. The working code is as follows:

```
$cursor = $collection->distinct('role', array("organization" => $curr_org['organization'], "role" => array('$exists' => true)));
foreach($cursor as $curr_org){
    echo '<ul>';
         echo '<li>';
              echo $curr_org;
         echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about are roles you could use [`MongoCollection::distinct`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.distinct.php)

```
$roles = $collection->distinct('role', array("organization" => $curr_org['organization']);
```

Comment: I see what you mean, I've changed my find to distinct and that does produce the correct number of results, so here is the new code replacing find "$cursor = $collection->distinct('role', array("organization" => $curr_org['organization'], "role" => array('$exists' => true)));" however it only displays the first character of each value and not the whole value. I've never seen this happen before. I'm a bit of a newbie with "distinct". Do you know how I can echo all my role value chars while using distinct?

Comment: `distinct` returns array of unique values (see the documentation for examples) so you just need to iterate over the array and echo what's in there.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. I did go through the distinct page prior to responding, however, that provided me nothing. Using the find() command returns the full string of each value, but when I converted to distinct(), I'm only echoing the first character of each distinct value. Example: "Boss Man" will echo using find(), but only "B" will echo using distinct().

Comment: Please paste your code, it sounds strange to say the least (like echoing `$result[0]` instead of `$result` when iterating over `distinct`'s results)

Comment: As I noted in previous comment, `distinct` returns array of unique values, so your code should be (without HTML parts) `$roles = /* distinct */; foreach ($roles as $role) { echo $role; }`

Comment: If I remove the HTML from the loop that stops producing my LI, and also has no impact on the result (I still only get first characters of each string) `$cursor = $collection->distinct('role', array("organization" => $curr_org['organization'], "role" => array('$exists' => true)));` `foreach($cursor as $curr_org){` `echo $curr_org['role'];` `}` produces the same result, but unlisted.

Comment: It's 3rd time I'm telling you that result of `distinct` is array of values, it's also outlined in the examples in the docs. So why are you still doing `echo $curr_org['role'];` in the loop?

Comment: Now I understand what you have been trying to describe. Remove `['role']` from the `$curr_org['role']` in the loop. It works now following this specific instruction. I also understand that I did not need to echo the specific value in the loop because it had been defined in the cursor command. The key in the loop caused the truncation because I was attempting to find within the already defined (found) results. Solved!

Comment: Original Code adjusted in the SOLVED section above.